# awk select rows that has column 1 partially matching column 2

Tags: awk

I have an "example_file" like below,

```
a2022.1 a2022.1 80
a2022.1 a2022.2 90
a2022.1 a2023.1 80
a2022.2 a2022.2 90
a2022.2 a2023.1 40
a2022.3 a2022.1 50
b20225.1 a2022.1 80
```

and I would like to select lines which has the third column > 80 and also has the 1st column (before the dot) different from the 2nd column (before the dot).

So the desired result would be

```
a2022.1 a2023.1 80
b20225.1 a2022.1 80
```

So I already managed to exclude the lines with 3rd column <80 and with the same 1st and 2nd column by using the line below

```
awk '($3 > 80 && $1!=$2)' example_file
```

and I tried `awk '($3 > 80 && $1!~$2)' example_file`, but it does not exclude the line

```
a2022.1 a2022.2 90
```

I thought it could be easy, but I can't figure it out. Could somebody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '[.[:blank:]]' '$NF >= 80 && $1 != $3' file

a2022.1 a2023.1 80
b20225.1 a2022.1 80
```

Here `-F '[.[:blank:]]'` sets input field separator to a dot or whitespace character. This allows us to use parts of first column as `$1` and `$2` and second column as `$3` and `$4`.

---

Alternatively using `gnu-awk`:

```bash
awk '$3 >= 80 && 
    gensub(/\..*/, "", "1", $1) != gensub(/\..*/, "", "1", $2)' file

a2022.1 a2023.1 80
b20225.1 a2022.1 80
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a simple line! I like it. Do you mind to explain me the `-F '[.[:blank:]]'`? I know `-F` is for setting the separation of the column, and I know that with this setting, the text is separated by both . and blank, right? and then why do we use `$NF`?

Comment: I have added explanation of `-F` option in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Using `split` function of `awk` here to get exact values from fields and compare them accordingly.

```bash
awk '
{
  split($1,arr1,".")
  split($2,arr2,".")
}
$3>=80 && arr1[1]!=arr2[1]
'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk` using it's `match` function please try following. Using regex `^.([^.]*)\..\s+.([^.]*)\..\s+(\S+)` for getting values as per requirement into the array(through capturing groups) and comparing them as per conditions in further condition.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/CK79mV/1) for used regex in following code.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^.([^.]*)\..\s+.([^.]*)\..\s+(\S+)/,arr) && (arr[3]>=80 && (arr[1]!=arr[2]))
'  Input_file
```

Comment: The split() function is nice, and this actually is what I thought to do at the very beginning, but didn't think of this function. Thanks! I also thought of match function, but I'm not so good at all the regex. Thanks for providing this option!

Comment: @zzz, Good to hear. I have also added Online regex demo(https://regex101.com/r/CK79mV/1) in my answer for your understanding. cheers.